# How can I install ansys, nastran or any designing software?

Tags: design

I install all design software in windows. But I don't know how to install any designing software in ubuntu. Will all these software will work in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use wine to run windows applications in ubuntu. But ansys and fem softwares take so much processing and wine cant handle that, wine even lags with autocad(3D). Its better you run them in windows. Use can dual boot between ubuntu and windwos.